# How to input a date string into telerik date picker textbox using selenium web driver C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
var dateTextBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_Content_TxtDateOfBirth_datePicker_dateInput"));

dateTextBox.Click();

dateTextBox.SendKeys(date);

driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSave")).Click();
```

I have a page where I have a Telerik date control with a textbox. The user inputs a date into the text box and clicks the save button.

For some reason when I run the test it enters the date into the text box but when it goes to save it clears the textbox of the date control so nothing is present in the date control text box.

Comment: are you possibly entering an incorrect date format into the text field? What's the date format supposed to be, and can you put date into your code snippet?

Comment: I can run the test manually the string i am passing to the send keys method is the same that i input 5/1/2015 i also tried 2015/5/1 which is the date format that Selenium uses when you record the test through the IDE both don't work. Another weird thing is that the method works sometimes but most of the time it clears the text box so when the page saves theres no date in the control.

Comment: No it has the problem both ways i just put the click command to see if that fixed the issue based on advice from other stack exchange posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the answer to this.

Really the only way to input a value into the telerik RAD Date picker is through javascript command

```
public void runScript(IWebDriver driver, String script)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    js.ExecuteScript(script);
}

public void setDatePicker(IWebDriver driver, String date, String Id)
{
    String script = string.Format("$find('{0}').set_selectedDate(new Date('{1}'))", Id, date);
    runScript(driver, script);
}
```

First i format a string for the java script command then run the runScript method which just executes the script. Hope this helps any future BAT developers who run into this in the future.